# Floats and Longs

Tags: c, memory

I used sizeof to check the sizes of longs and floats in my `64` bit amd opteron machine.  Both show up as 4.

When I check `limits.h` and `float.h` for maximum float and long values these are the values I get:

```
Max value of Float:340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

Max value of long:9223372036854775807
```

Since they both are of the same size, how can a float store such a huge value when compared to the long?

I assume that they have a different storage representation for float.  If so, does this impact performance:ie ,is using longs faster than using floats?

Comment: Something isn't right. If `sizeof(long) == 4`, then the max value of `long` should only be `2147483647`.

Comment: The long value is wrong for only 32 bits.  It should only be about 2 billion.

Comment: Some 64 bit ABIs have 32 bit longs and 64 bit long longs -- others use 64 bits for both.

Comment: These max values were printed out from float.h and limits.h respectively.. now that I look into it, it makes sense that it shouldnt be that big

Comment: if sizeof(long) = 4, then the longest max value is indeed 2147483647 and you are misinterpreting the contents of limits.h, perhaps mistaking the maximum value of a long long for that of a long.

Answer (score 6):

It is a tradeoff.

A 32 bit signed integer can express every integer between -2<sup>31</sup> and +2<sup>31</sup>-1.

A 32 bit float uses exponential notation and can express a much wider range of numbers, but would be unable to express all of the numbers in the range -- not even all of the integers. It uses some of the bits to represent a fraction, and the rest to represent an exponent. It is effectively the binary equivalent of a notation like 6.023*10<sup>23</sup> or what have you, with the distance between representable numbers quite large at the ends of the range.

For more information, I would read this article, "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic" by David Goldberg: http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf

By the way, on your platform, I would expect a float to be a 32 bit quantity and a long to be a 64 bit quantity, but that isn't really germane to the overall point.

Performance is kind of hard to define here. Floating point operations may or may not take significantly longer than integer operations depending on the nature of the operations and whether hardware acceleration is used for them. Typically, operations like addition and subtraction are much faster in integer -- multiplication and division less so. At one point, people trying to bum every cycle out when doing computation would represent real numbers as "fixed point" arithmetic and use integers to represent them, but that sort of trick is much rarer now. (On an Opteron, such as you are using, floating point arithmetic is indeed hardware accelerated.)

Almost all platforms that C runs on have distinct "float" and "double" representations, with "double" floats being double precision, that is, a representation that occupies twice as many bits. In addition to the space tradeoff, operations on these are often somewhat slower, and again, people highly concerned about performance will try to use floats if the precision of their calculation does not demand doubles.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to matter whether operations on `long` are faster than operations on `float`, or vice versa.

If you only need to represent whole number values, use an integer type.  Which type you should use depends on what you're using it for (signed vs. unsigned, `short` vs. `int` vs. `long` vs. `long long`, or one of the exact-width types in `<stdint.h>`).

If you need to represent real numbers, use one of the floating-point types: `float`, `double`, or `long double`.  (`float` is actually not used much unless memory space is at a premium; `double` has better precision and often is no slower than `float`.)

In short, choose a type whose semantics match what you need, and worry about performance later.  There's no great advantageously in getting wrong answers quickly.

As for storage representation, the other answers have pretty much covered that.  Typically unsigned integers user all their bits to represent the value, signed integers devote one bit to representing the sign (though usually not directly), and floating-point types devote one bit for the sign, a few bits for an exponent, and the rest for the value.  (That's a gross oversimplification.)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point maths is a subject all to itself, but yes: int types are typically faster than float types.

One trick to remember is that not all values can be expressed as a float.
e.g. the closest you may be able to get to 1.9 is 1.899999999. This leads to fun bugs where you say if (v == 1.9) things behave unexpectedly!

Comment: The case that I am using is that, I only use whole numbers(not decimal numbers).  I need to express numbers that are longer than integers.  So long is the ideal way to go.  But for some reason, the library that I am using crashes when I use longs.. but it works fine when it uses floats.  So I am trying to use floats in place of longs.  Will floats miss the storage of whole numbers by any chance?

Comment: Any given API call will take only one type of number. If you are wondering why it crashes when you feed it the wrong type of data, I would suggest that you might not understand the way the C type system works yet -- it might pay to spend some time reading up on it, because this is not the only place where you will have trouble with it.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman: Terminology is important.  You don't need to express numbers that are longer than *integers* (there are no such numbers), you need to express numbers that are longer than `int`s.  `int` is one of several integer types.  `long` is another.

Answer (score 0):

> If so, does this impact performance: ie, is using longs faster than using floats?

Yes, arithmetic with `long`s will be faster than with `float`s.

> I assume that they have a different storage representation for float.

Yes.  The `float` types are in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (single precision) format.

> Since they both are of the same size, how can a float store such a huge value when compared to the long?

It's optimized to store numbers at a few points (near 0 for example), but it's not optimized to be accurate.  For example you could add 1 to 1000000000.  With the `float`, there probably won't be any difference in the sum (1000000000 instead of 1000000001), but with the `long` there will be.

Comment: It's not *necessarily* the case that `long` arithmetic will be faster than `float` arithmetic.  Some systems are heavily optimized for floating-point.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, true, but I'm guessing the AMD Opteron the OP stated isn't one of those.